# ajax will not send canvas data to php

Tags: php, ajax, png, send

This is the code in my js

```
(function(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    photo = document.getElementById('photo'),
    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    datas = canvas.toDataURL('images/png');

    navigator.getMedia =    navigator.getUserMedia || 
                            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    navigator.getMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: false
    }, function(stream){
        video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, function(error){

    });

    document.getElementById('capture').addEventListener('click',function(){
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);
        photo.setAttribute('src', canvas.toDataURL('images/png'));


        datas = canvas.toDataURL('images/png');



    });
    var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST",'webcam.php',false);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
        ajax.send(canvasData);


})();
```

This is the php code to receive the data

```
<?php

    if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    echo "true";
  // Get the data
  $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

  // Remove the headers (data:,) part.
  // A real application should use them according to needs such as to check image type
  $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

  // Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded
  $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

  //echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;

  // Save file. This example uses a hard coded filename for testing,
  // but a real application can specify filename in POST variable
  $fp = fopen( 'test.png', 'wb' );
  fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
  fclose( $fp );
}
?>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <Title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="booth">
            <video id = "video" width="400" height="300"></video>
            <a href="#" id ="capture" class="booth-capture-button">Snap Shot</a>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
            <img id ="photo" name = "photo" src="images/events/default.png" alt="Photo of you">
        </div>

    <script src="js/photo.js"></script>
    </body>

<?php  


?>
```

The application intends to take a snapshot of the user and saves the photo via javascript. I am trying to find a way to send the data back to php and utilize it to save into the database. I understand it is saved in base64 encode. I tried different methods of Ajax including the one I have saved, but the data tends to not send any data to the php folder.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I just suggest you to check some of you code points:

1. Form content type. To upload files you must use "multipart/form-data"

   ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
2. You can use FormData class in JS to make form data before sending:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData/append
3. Canvas function "toDataURL" have no mime types "images/png". Just "image/png"

Comment: No dice, tried both methods and nothing is sent to the php.